# Missing instructions and box

Tags: set-identification

My mom bought this set at a garage sale, with no instructions and no box. There are some obvious identifying pieces but I don’t know what set they are from, or if I even have all the pieces I need. I also don’t know if the wheels that came with it are actually part of the set. Any help appreciated! (2011 on the bag)[image]

Answer (score 6):

The loose part are gray and red speeder from: [75012-1: BARC Speeder with Sidecar](https://brickset.com/sets/75012-1/BARC-Speeder-with-Sidecar)

[image]

based on:

[Coupling Plate 2X2](https://brickset.com/parts/4211419/coupling-plate-2x2) in Medium Stone Grey

[Roof Tile 2X1X2](https://brickset.com/parts/4645101/roof-tile-2x1x2) in New Dark Red

[Lt Suspension](https://brickset.com/parts/4566872/lt-suspension) in Dark Stone Grey

Comment: Thank you!! My son will be very happy to hear that it’s from Star Wars! Now to get the instructions! :)

Comment: @Katie The brickset link Joost included has a tab for "Instructions" that could make this easier to find for you.